# When adding a figure, following paragraph text is affected

Tags: spacing, floats, paragraphs

I'm adding an image to my 2 column paper using:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{myimage.png}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label{mylabel}
\end{figure}
```

Immediately before the image gets added there is no spacing between paragraphs, but immediately after it there is ~5mm spacing added between paragraphs.

When I remove the figure, the paragraph spacing goes away.

Any idea why?

---

A few other details:

- If I change `width=0.48\textwidth` to `\columnwidth` the same problem occurs, however if I change `width=\textwidth`, the image runs off the page, but the paragraph spacing issue goes away.

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: Really it would be better if you showed an example it is hard to debug unseen code, but perhaps it is the issue here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=21516617#21516617

Comment: @Johannes_B that fixed it! wow, wacky, but I'll take it! Could you post it as an answer. David Carlisle, good point, I'd do so, but Johannes_B seems to have nailed it already. Thanks for the responses both of you!

Comment: Once I went searching for usage of `\raggedbottom` I found this similar case, linked here for reference: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4209, incidentally, `\raggedbottom` goes in the preamble.